# 100% height div but if content bigger adjust accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen

My website is to be a one page website, with 5 DIV's acting as panels (with a classname as .panel) that fit to stretch the full height and width of the browser window. My below code does this already and works a treat however, I have content that can be larger than the height of .panel/browser window. At the moment this content gets hidden. I.e. The .panel DIV is literally the height of the window and nothing else. I need it to expand if the content within it is larger than the height of the browser window.

How do I edit this code below to do add this functionality? Maybe add a classname to this adjusted DIV so that I can style it accordingly?

```
// In my plugins.js file
function fitElements(){
var height=$(window).height();
var width=$(window).width();

$('.panel').css('height',height);
$('.panel').css('width',width)
};

// At the bottom of my HTML file (to call the function)
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    fitElements();
});

// My current code also adjusts on browser resize - so would need this answer to do the same
 $(window).resize(fitElements);
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using the function directly in the resize callback? `$(window).resize(fitElements());`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You are using an anonymous function in the callback of `.resize()` only to call another function.

Comment: So it should be this code instead? $(window).resize(fitElements());

Comment: Sorry that should be [`$(window).resize(fitElements);`](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz2EK/). And it will also work inside the anonymous function, but when it is not needed why do it? :-)

Comment: Ok cheers. I'm not so quick with jQuery and I haven't quite got the best practices down yet. I'd appreciate your input, if you have any, towards my question originally asked :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the section

```
$('.panel').css('height',height);
```

to

```
if (height > $('.panel').height) {
   $('.panel').css('height',height);
}
```

for the re-size function add

```
$('.panel').css('height','auto');
```

in to the beginning of the function

Comment: Thanks for this, but it seems to have broken the panels that have content less than the height of the browser. Does this need to be an if else?

Comment: this is only works when the site have the "content less than the height of the browser"